# Java scanner test for empty line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using Scanner to read 3 lines of input, the first two are strings and the last one is int.
I'm having an issue when the first line is empty and I don't know how to get around it. I have to do this:

```
String operation = sc.nextLine();
String line = sc.nextLine();
int index = sc.nextInt();
encrypt(operation,line,index);
```

But when the first line is empty I get an error message. 
I tried the following to force a loop until I get a non empty next line but it does not work either:

```
        while(sc.nextLine().isEmpty){
        operation = sc.nextLine();}
```

Anybody has a hint please ?

Comment: Maybe not using a scanner but a reader...

Comment: Show your code with the loop. It should have worked.

Comment: Also, you forgot to call `isEmpty`

Comment: You are calling `nextLine` twice and when it is called it consumes what is in the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop should work, though you must actually call the isEmpty method and scan only once per iteration

```
String operation = "";
do {
    operation = sc.nextLine();
} while(operation.isEmpty());
```

You could also use `sc.hasNextLine()` to check if anything is there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
    String firstNotEmptyLine = "";
    while (scanner.hasNext() && firstNotEmptyLine.equals("")) {
        firstNotEmptyLine = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    if (!scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.err.println("This whole file is filled with empty lines! (or the file is just empty)");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(firstNotEmptyLine);
```

Then you can read the other two lines after this `firstNotEmptyLine`.

Comment: A previous answer worked for me but I think this should too, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String operation = null;
    String line = null;
    int index = 0;
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
        if(!nextLine.isEmpty()) {
            operation = nextLine;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
        if(!nextLine.isEmpty()) {
            line = nextLine;
            break;
        }
    }

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
        if(!nextLine.isEmpty()) {
            index = Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(operation + " " + line + " " + index);
```

Comment: `sc.nextLine.isEmpty()` - are you sure?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the issue, I have fixed and came up with better solution. :)

Comment: A previous answer worked for me but I think this should too, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
    String operation = sc.nextLine();
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    int index = sc.nextInt();

    test(operation,line,index);

}

public static void encrypt(String a,String b,int c){

    System.out.println("first :"+a+" Second :"+b+" Third :"+c);

}
```

I don't see any error here. It compiles well.